# Whatsapp email message split into date and messages

Tags: javascript, split, match, break, whatsapp

I try use the regex:

```
 /(\d{2}[\/]){2}(\d{2})[,][ ]\d{2}[:]\d{2}([ ][\-]){1}[ ]{1}/
```

to split the string

"24/03/18, 19:23 - As mensagens enviadas a este grupo estão agora protegidas com a criptografia de ponta-a-ponta. Toque para obter mais informações.
‎24/03/18, 14:41 - ‎‪+55 61 9982-6837‬ criou o grupo "English for dummies"
‎24/03/18, 19:23 - Você entrou usando o link de convite deste grupo ..."

into many groups and capture the date and the text after the date.

But, the result is:

[ '‎',

```
  '03/',

  '18',

  ' -',

  'As mensagens enviadas a este grupo estão agora protegidas com a criptografia de ponta-a-ponta. Toque para obter mais informações.\n‎', 
...
]
```

Expected result:

[
'24/03/18, 19:23',
'As mensagens enviadas a este grupo estão agora protegidas com a criptografia de ponta-a-ponta. Toque para obter mais informações.\n‎',
...
]

Can any people help me?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: Get the date and the messages at a array.

Comment: Please post the expected output. You say the date and messages, but that's _very_ broad.

Comment: Sorry. I can resolve the problem. The answer is below.

Comment: It should only be one answer, not two. But regardless, the question is still low quality.

Comment: Sorry. I will make the corrections.

Answer (score 1):

I split the date with the regex expression:

```
/\d{2}[\/{2}]\d{2}[\/]\d{2}, \d{2}:\d{2} - /
```

And get the message. I try to found a way of get the date.

Answer (score 0):

A can  split the two items with the regex:

```
/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}, \d{2}:\d{2} - )/
```

And get the message at two lines in array.